# Access Token Meta Data via Solscan API with Python

Tags: python-requests, solana

I try to access the meta data of a solana token via the Solscan API.

The following code works in principle but the API doesn't provide the expected data.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'
}

params = {
    'token': '24jvtWN7qCf5GQ5MaE7V2R4SUgtRxND1w7hyvYa2PXG6',
}

response = requests.get('https://api.solscan.io/token/meta', headers=headers, params=params)

print(response.content.decode())
```

It returns:

{"succcess":true,"data":{"holder":1}}

However, I expected the following according to the docs https://public-api.solscan.io/docs/#/Token/get_token_meta:

[image]

Any help? Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried this with another token and got the full response. It seems like the example SPL is lacking metadata to display.

```
import requests
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict

url = "https://public-api.solscan.io/token/meta?tokenAddress=4k3Dyjzvzp8eMZWUXbBCjEvwSkkk59S5iCNLY3QrkX6R"

headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
headers["accept"] = "application/json"


resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(resp.status_code)
```